# Git delete uncessesary commits (log) as Updates README.md

Tags: git

First, I want to eliminate all commits which specify a commit message of 'Update README.md'

**The problem** is that I have more than 50 commits where most are "Update README.md" with minimal edits.

I can filter with this,

```
git log --grep="Update README.md"
```

How can I go about actually deleting them?

or, I would like to be able to make changes to `README.md` without generating more unnecessary commits.

Comment: why do you want to do this ? why do you think you you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve.  It sounds to me like you are asking how to implement a solution instead of asking the ACTUAL quesion. ( X-Y problem )

Comment: I've changed some things. What do you think now?

Comment: I think you made it worse.  The sentence you added is unclear, uses very broken language and doesn't specify make a problem any clearer.  WHY DO YOU THINK IT IS A PROBLEM for these commits to exist and have the same message?? Why is it a problem for commits when the file is changed?    Frankly I would say it is not; this is how Git works.

Comment: Jumm Understand, Sure I should delete post... Thank you very much dude, give up in this coment for delete post. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: no worries just trying to help out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: Be sure to make a backup before trying it**

First you must copy the file which have so many unnecesary commits, then

Use git `rebase -i HEAD~NUMEROFCOMMITS` to show commits

**Note**: if have problem in some method, you can use

```
git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
```

### Method One(Recommended):

instead of deleting commits and replace files could use `squash` for combine commits

use: `git rebase -i HEAD~NUMBEROFCOMMITS` and then the commits will be shown

**Change** `pick` by `squash` in lines of commits that want you combine and save, then:

**Execute**: `git push origin +master`

---

### Method Two:

for my case:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~50
```

then in the console delete all commits with the name "Update README.md" except the ultimate and save file, now use `git add .` and `git commit -a`

Now replace the file to which he was removed the commit by the copy that you save at the beginning

finally force push with:

```
git push origin +master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make changes to a file stored in GIT without a commit; so I suggest you revisit the question of why do you care about commits that update `README.mk` being in your history or not.

If you 'delete' the commits the changes will be undone. If you squash them into other commits, you are changing the hash of everything you've done and this will disrupt everyone else in the repo.

Summary:  You really need to explain why you think you need to do this; because on the surface you shouldn't be doing this.

If you haven't merged your branch yet to master by all means go ahead and rewrite your branches history and squash things together.  However you haven't made it clear which branch you are on, which branch you want to revise, etc.

Comment: You have reason, I understand too little about git

Comment: which think you that could be the solution to `README.md without generating more unnecessary commits.` ? I Think `squash` maybe can help... What do you think?

Comment: There is NO solution and there wont be a solution. EVERY CHANGE TO EVERY FILE IS A COMMIT

I suggest instead you make more detailed messages , specify what you are changing in that file, and only allow one commit that edits that file per merge to master.